# Obtaining Daily Logs

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'd like to know how I could get Daily logs from Field Management in a JSON format.
What is the endpoint I should query and how to do it?
I have found the following documentation earlier, but it does not give any example of how I should request the required data (daily logs) via API:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/field-guide/data-connector/
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/data-connector/dc-tutorial-submit-data-request/

Thanks,

Henrique Alexandre

Comment: Hey guys. I've managed to submit the request following the example I found in another place and got back a message like this:

{"id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","description":"DL by Month","isActive":true,"accountId":"XXXXXXXXX","createdBy":"XXXXXX","createdByEmail":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","createdAt":"2021-04-29T16:34:06.122Z","updatedBy":"XXXXXXXX","updatedAt":"2021-04-29T16:34:06.122Z","scheduleInterval":"MONTH","reoccuringInterval":2,"effectiveFrom":"2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","effectiveTo":"2021-04-30T00:00:00.000Z","lastQueuedAt":null,"serviceGroups":["dailylogs"],"callbackUrl":null,"sendEmail":true}

Comment: Should I not get a file or a JSON with the content from the Daily Logs area?

Answer (score 0):

the response data you got above is just the request which starts the extraction job. When the job is done, you can get data list, next get data signed url , finally download the data as csv. I'd suggest you take a look at the tutorial:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/data-connector/dc-tutorial-retrieve-data-extract/
and the Postman collection.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-data.connector.api-postman.collection
It provides the endpoints test step by step.

Comment: How longs does it take for the job to be done?

Comment: normally, it will be done in reasonable time as it extracts data from the database of BIM360 server directly. Due to the volumes of projects/service data, it has not exact time estimation, but the performance is good. While if you find any issues, please do not hesitate to contact us. . In addition ,I would suggest your code setup a callback endpoint to watch the completion. When creating Request, it allows you to specify the callback url

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Xiaodong.
I followed the official docs and imported your collection but when I submit the jobs request I always get an empty array as an answer:

{
    "pagination": {
        "limit": 20,
        "offset": 0,
        "totalResults": 0
    },
    "results": []
}

I also would like to know if it's possible to specify the projects I want to retrieve the information from.
Thanks,

Henrique

Comment: Henrique, could you share the payload how you requested? in addition, will it work if you request in UI (product)? As to retrieve data of specific project, it is on the plan of near term, though I cannot guarantee the exact time.

Comment: "callbackUrl":"https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback","
description":"Test-Logs",
"effectiveFrom":"2021-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"effectiveTo":"2021-05-14T00:00:00Z",
"reoccuringInterval":5,
"scheduleInterval":"WEEK",
"serviceGroups":["admin","checklists","dailylogs","issues","locations","submittals","cost","rfis"]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Xiaodong.
Does the PowerBI connector have the same limitation in regards to Daily Logs, RFIs, Submittals and other data sets only available via the Data Connector Endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Forge API for PowerBI at a moment.  But if you are talking about the template posted here:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/BIM360D-Insight/files/BIM360D-Insight-data-extractor-html-html.html

The types of data being extracted are the same as using Data Connector features in the UI under Insight. The same applies to API. No additional data. API allows you to automate the process and gives a granular access for scheduling intervals and access to individual csv files. If you are not getting any data through the API, as a part of troubleshoot, you first want to verify if you can access to the data through the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
What is this connector about then?
https://www.autodesk.com/bim-360/power-bi-template-construction-projects/

What are the datasets this connector is able to retrieve?
Thanks,

Henrique

Comment: This page lists the list of data accessible currently: 
https://help.autodesk.com/view/BIM360D/ENU/?guid=BIM360D_Insight_data_extractor_html
You can find a schema under schemas folder when you download the zip file.  
The data is used for creating analytics in Insight module.

Answer (score 0):

@Henrique Alexandre,  checking the payload you specified, I’d believe the problem is from effectiveFrom. What you input it a time (2021-01-01) before current time when you created the request.

If the request is ONE_TIME, effectiveFrom could be before current time, execution of scheduling begins immediately. However, when it is the scheduler of other type (like WEEK), be careful not to set effectiveFrom, effectiveTo to the past time.

In the demo Postman collection, I pre-set the time as below. i.e. make the effectiveFrom a few minutes after calling the endpoint of creating request.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-data.connector.api-postman.collection

```
var d = new Date()
 var current_time = d.getFullYear() 
            +"-" + (("0" + (d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) )
            + "-" +  ("0" + d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) 
            + "T" +("0" + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) 
            + ":" + ("0" + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) 
            + ":" + ("0" + d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2) 
            + ".000Z"
pm.environment.set("current_time", current_time);

d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes()+2) // start execute after 2 minutes

var effective_from = d.getUTCFullYear() 
            +"-" + (("0" + (d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) )
            + "-" +  ("0" + d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) 
            + "T" +("0" + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) 
            + ":" + ("0" + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2)
            + ":" + ("0" + d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2) 
            + ".000Z"
pm.environment.set("effective_from", effective_from);

d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()+10) // end execute after 10 days

var effective_to = d.getUTCFullYear() 
            +"-" + (("0" + (d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) )
            + "-" +  ("0" + d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) 
            + "T" +("0" + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) 
            + ":" + ("0" + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2)
            + ":" + ("0" + d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2) 
            + ".000Z"
pm.environment.set("effective_to", effective_to);
```

If the problem still exsits, we could setup a meeting to diagnose remotely.

In addition, it looks you are trying to set callback with
"getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
I might be ignorant, but as I know this callback is only used for Postman authorization workflow. I am not sure where you could get the notification data from Data Connector. For test purpose, if you do not want to build callback, some 3rd party tool could be useful such as https://requestbin.com/.

As the PowerBI question, Mikako has replied you.

Comment: I also would like to understand your recommendation in regards to the callback URL field. Could you please provide an example? If I don't specify that or leave in the way it is, what is the difference?

Comment: Still getting this reply:
    "developerMessage": "The requested resource does not exist.",
    "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
    "errorCode": ""

Payload was changed according to your instructions:

{"callbackUrl":"https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback","description":"Test-Logs","effectiveFrom":"2022-08-20T00:00:00Z","effectiveTo":"2022-08-21T00:00:00Z","reoccuringInterval":5,"scheduleInterval":"ONE_TIME","serviceGroups":["admin","checklists","dailylogs","issues","locations","submittals","cost","rfis"]}